# Indexing PDF files with Solr 6.6 while allowing highlighting matched text with context

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and I need to implement a full-text search of some PDF files. The indexing part works out of the box by using `bin/post`. I can see search results in the admin UI given some queries, though without the matched texts and the context.

Now I am reading [this post](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/05/27/hilight-matched-text-inside-documents-indexed-with-solr-plus-tika/) for the highlighting part. It is for an older version of Solr when managed schema was not available. Before fully understand what it is doing I have some questions:

1. He defined two fields:

```
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

But why are there two fields needed? Can I define a field

```
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

to capture the full text?

2. How are the fields filled? I don't see relevant information in [`TikaEntityProcessor`'s documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0/solr-dataimporthandler-extras/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/TikaEntityProcessor.html#fields.inherited.from.class.org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorBase). The current text extractor should already be Tika (I can see

```
"x_parsed_by":
    ["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser","org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser"]
```

in the returned JSON of some query). But even I define the fields as he said I cannot see them in the search results as keys in JSON.

3. The `_text_` field seems a concatenation of other fields, does it contain the full text? Though it does not seem to be accessible by default.

To be brief, using [The Elements of
Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf) as an example, how to highlight the relevant texts for the query "SVM"? And if changing the file name into "The Elements of Statistical Learning - Trevor Hastie.pdf" and post it, how to highlight "Trevor Hastie" for the query "id:Trevor Hastie"?

Answer (score 2):

Before I get started on the questions let me just give a brief how solr works. Solr in its core uses lucene when simply put is a matching engine. It creates inverted indexes of document with the phrases. What this means is for each phrase it has a list of documents which makes it so fast. Getting to your questions:

Solr does not convert your pdf to text,well its the update processor configured in the handler which does it ,again this can be configured in solrconfig.xml or write your own handler [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors). 
Coming back why are there two fields. To simply put the first one(content) is a stored field which stores the data as it is. And the second one is a copyfield which copies the data for each document as per the configuration in schema.xml.

We do this because we can then choose the indexing strategy such as we add a lowercase filter factory to text field so that everything is indexed in lower case. Then "Sam" and "sam" when searched returns the same results.Or remove certain common occurring words such as "a","the" which will unnecessarily increase your index size. Which uses a lot of memory when you are dealing with millions of records, then you want to be careful which fields to index to better utilise the resources.
The field "text" is a copyfield which copies data from certain fields as mentioned in the schema to text field. Then when searching in general one does not need to fire multiple queries for each field. As everything thing is copied into "text" field and you get the result. This is the reason it's "multivaled". As it can stores an array of data. Content is a stored field and text is not,and opposite for indexed because when you return your result to the end user you show him what ever you saved not the stripped down data that you just did with the text field applying multiple filters(such as removing stop words and applying case filters,stemming etc).

This is the reason you do not see "text" field in the search result as this is used solr.
For highlighting see [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting).

For more these are some great blog [yonik](http://yonik.com/) and [joel](http://joelsolr.blogspot.in/).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I now understand more about those fields. But still, I don't see the `content` field in the returned JSON after following the setting (defining `content` and `text` according to the same field settings as in the post, then copying `content` to `text`) and re-indexing. How can I check whether they are filled by the text extractor, without writing my own extraction code? (Or do I have to handle the text extraction myself?)

Comment: OK, I actually need to map `fmap.content` to `content` rather than `_text_` as done by the defaults.